# Remove innerHTML from div

Tags: jquery, innerhtml

I'm trying to clear the div's innerHTML before repopulating it.  I tried removeData() but once that's called, when I try to add the data, I get nothing from the next line after remove whereas if I remove the removeData() it's fine again.  I just want to clear out any previous content in that div before I re-populate it.

```
    divToUpdate.removeData(); //clean out any existing innerHTML div content first
    divToUpdate.html(data);
```

It looks like it never gets to my divToUpdate.html(data) for some reason after it calls that removeData();

Answer (score 119):

jQuery Data is a different concept than HTML.  removeData is not for removing element content, it's for removing data items you've previously stored.

Just do

```
divToUpdate.html("");
```

or

```
divToUpdate.empty();
```

Answer (score 29):

To remove all child elements from your div:

```
$('#mysweetdiv').empty();
```

`.removeData()` and the corresponding `.data()` function are used to attach data behind an element, say if you wanted to note that a specific list element referred to user ID 25 in your database:

```
var $li = $('<li>Joe</li>').data('id', 25);
```

Comment: how to select using this li?

Answer (score 9):

```
$('div').html('');
```

But why are you clearing, `divToUpdate.html(data);` will completely replace the old HTML.

Comment: because I believe that the div in the parent page is retaining the old innerHTML every time I close and reopen the jQuery UI Dialog

Comment: How do you know this?  what are you referencing that tells you other than looking at the div content that it clears it out?

Comment: In the jQuery documentation (http://api.jquery.com/html/) "A string of HTML to set as the content of each matched element." I interpret the work "set" to mean replace. To verify this I could do something like alert($('div').html()) between the two lines of code to verify.

Answer (score 4):

```
divToUpdate.innerHTML =     "";
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var $div = $('#desiredDiv');
$div.contents().remove();
$div.html('<p>This is new HTML.</p>');
```

That should work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

you should be able to just overwrite it without removing previous data